# Is it possible to implement an international shopping cart using Stripe Connect?

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-gateway

Reading Stripe Connect's docs it doesn't seem like you can do this

> Stripe supports separate charges and transfers in the following
> regions: Australia, Europe, Japan, New Zealand, and the U.S. Separate
> charges and transfers are supported only if both your platform and the
> connected account are in the same region (for example, both in
> Australia).

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers

From what I understanding, if someone has multiple things in their shopping cart they can't buy them all at once unless all the sellers are located in the same country.

Is there any way to work around this for a shopping cart feature?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can make multiple charges using [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) and send payouts to the appropriate sellers.

I have yet to implement this solution. Once done, I'll update this answer with my findings.